# Recoding rare categories of a variable to category -"other" based on condition

Tags: r, data-processing

Need to transform variable below, based on category quantity in the dataset

so that categories that appear less than two times are re-named to category "other"

**Data example**

[image]

**Desirable output**

[image]

I used to use below chunk of code for such transformation but since I moved to R 4.05 it throws me an error.

```
levels(data$Country_of_origin) <-ifelse(table(data&Country_of_origin)>2,"OTHER",levels(data&Country_of_origin))
```

Comment: Could probably be done with `forcats::fct_count` and `forcats::fct_collapse`.

Comment: Is the `&` in `data&Country_of_origin` intentional, rather than `$`?

Comment: BTW I was looking for a way to group the "rare" categories in a univariate categorical variable automatically. Like if I have A, B, C, D, E in which D and E have contributions of just 0.02, and 0.01 respectively, then it would be beneficial to group them as the "other" category. Now, handpicking a threshold like <0.05 won't work for all cases. My question is if there is a way to automatically get the threshold or some kind of dynamic threshold from the given distribution to detect the "rare" categories. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why your code stopped working but [`forcats::fct_lump_*()`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html) is a great option for this application. See small example here:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- c('USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Japan', 'USA', 'USA') %>% factor()

# original distribution
table(d)
#> d
#> Germany   Japan     USA 
#>       1       1       4

# lumpped distribution
fct_lump_min(d, min = 2) %>% table()
#> .
#>   USA Other 
#>     4     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

### Packages

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
```

## Input

```
data <- tibble( country = c('USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Japan', 'USA', 'USA'))
```

### data

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  country
  <chr>  
1 USA    
2 USA    
3 Germany
4 Japan  
5 USA    
6 USA
```

## Solution

```
few_country <- data %>% count(country) %>% filter(n<=2) 
    
data %>% 
   mutate(new_country = case_when(country %in% few_country$country ~ "OTHER",
                                     TRUE ~ country))
```

## Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  country new_country
  <chr>   <chr>      
1 USA     USA        
2 USA     USA        
3 Germany OTHER      
4 Japan   OTHER      
5 USA     USA        
6 USA     USA
```

Comment: BTW I was looking for a way to group the "rare" categories in a univariate categorical variable automatically. Like if I have A, B, C, D, E in which D and E have contributions of just 0.02, and 0.01 respectively, then it would be beneficial to group them as the "other" category. Now, handpicking a threshold like <0.05 won't work for all cases. My question is if there is a way to automatically get the threshold or some kind of dynamic threshold from the given distribution to detect the "rare" categories. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, you can calculate frequency after `group_by(country)` and then mutate `country` when below a threshold:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble( country = c('USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Japan', 'USA', 'USA'))

data |>
  group_by(country) |>
  mutate(country = ifelse(n() < 2, "OTHER", country))

# A tibble: 6 × 1
# Groups:   country [2]
  country
  <chr>  
1 USA    
2 USA    
3 OTHER  
4 OTHER  
5 USA    
6 USA
```